# Microsoft Websocket Code Example Returning Error

Tags: javascript, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I'm trying to set up a websocket connection with Excel 365 custom functions, and have copy-pasted the code directly from Microsoft's website here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-web-reqs

```
let ws = new WebSocket('wss://bundles.office.com');

ws.onmessage(message) {
    console.log(`Received: ${message}`);
}

ws.onerror(error){
    console.err(`Failed: ${error}`);
}
```

Obviously I must be missing something, because the code above doesn't run.

```
"Line #3: ';' expected.
 ws.onmessage(message)

Line #7: ';' expected.
 ws.onerror(error)
```

Also when I mouse over "message", it reads this: Cannot find name 'message'. Did you mean 'onmessage'?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The sample code need to be updated. Could you try below:

```
let ws = new WebSocket('wss://bundles.office.com');
```

ws.onmessage = function (message) {
    console.log(`Received: ${message}`);
}

ws.onerror = function (error){
    console.error(`Failed: ${error}`);
}

Note: `wss://bundles.office.com` is just a sample. It’s not really available for test.